# How Do I import React.jsx file to my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, carousel, react-slick

So I've been trying to import an image carousel from my jsx my html file. I've added the necessary scripts to my .html and "npm install react-slick carousel". Nothing is coming up once I load my browser. Help a brother out. Here is my code so far.

**HTML file**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.6.2/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.6.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

     <title>Friend With Benefits</title> </head> <body>

     <header>
         <div id="fwb">
             <button onclick="window.location.reload();">Friend With Benefits (FWB)</button>
         </div>

         <div class="register">
             <button>Sign Up</button>
         </div>

         <div>
             <button>Login</button>
         </div>

     </header>

     <div class="carousel">
         <script src="carousel.jsx"></script>
     </div>

     <button id="prevBtn;">Prev</button>
     <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

     <div class="profile">
         SLIDESHOW
     </div>

     <div class="gym">

         <img src="">

         <blockquote>
             FWB is collaborating with Gold's Gym, American Family, and YouFit. If a friend
             brings in enough people to a gym they will be rewarded points towards their gym membership.<br>
             Points can earn a friend perks such as: discounts, complementary gym accessories, and free membership
             for a month.
         </blockquote>

     </div>

     <div class="cost">

         <img src="">

         <blockquote>The yearly cost for FWB is only $50.<br>Free trial for the first month. Will notify three days before trial is over to
 avoid automated payment.</blockquote>

     </div>

     <div class="quote">
         SLIDESHOW
     </div>

     <footer class="footer">



     </footer>


 </body> </html>
```

**JSX file**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"; import Slider from
 "react-slick";

 export default class SimpleSlider extends Component {   render() {
     const settings = {
       dots: true,
       infinite: true,
       speed: 500,
       slidesToShow: 1,
       slidesToScroll: 1
     };
     return (
       <div>
         <Slider {...settings}>
           <div><img src="partner1.png" alt="one"/></div>
           <div><img src="partner2.jpg" alt="two"/></div>
           <div><img src="partner3.jpg" alt="three"/></div>
           <div><img src="partner4.jpg" alt="four"/></div>
           <div><img src="partner5.jpg" alt="five"/></div>
           <div><img src="partner6.jpg" alt="six"/></div>
         </Slider>
       </div>
     );   } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers only understand HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. JSX is not a standard language of the web.

It was introduced to provide an easier syntax for React, and it is optional. In order to add React JSX code to your website, you need to

1. Get React itself.
2. Get Babel. Babel is a transpiler, meaning it will convert your JSX to traditional JavaScript. Again, JSX is optional in React.
3. Get ReactDOM. ReactDOM allows you to render components in your HTML by selecting the element under which you want your elements to be rendered.

Since you want to add React with JSX to an HTML page, you can do it quickly by using CDNs as described in this tutorial:
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

This approach is good enough for learning React, may not be good for your project if your project becomes so large you might need several components.

In that case, see create-react-app:
https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had tried a similar challenge, but found that with inline React babel reference. JSX imports do not work.
with inline script a simple jsx ie without imports will work

```js
<script type="text/babel">

  const MyComponent = () => {
    return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
  };

  ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('renyReactApp'));
</script>
```

Did u check you F12 debugger. There would and error that < is not recogni

Comment: Hey, thanks for pitching in on StackOverflow! Your answer seems a bit unclear and might leave readers scratching their heads. Could you provide more context or clarify your points to make it easier to follow? Feel free to [edit] your answer for better clarity and understanding.

Answer (score -1):

The way you are using react is incorrect.
JSX is not understood by the browser. It understands HTML, CSS, and JS.
To make it understandable we use a babel transpiler which converts JSX into readable format for the browser.
So technically you have to first transpile jsx code to js and then use it.
Also, the way you are importing the carousel.jsx is incorrect. You have to render it into a root element.

https://www.w3schools.com/REACT/showreact.asp?filename=demo2_react_test